# Find a solution curve that connects a saddle point.

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

The entire problem is as follows:

Consider $\dot{x} = y+x^2-y^2$ and $\dot{y} = -x-2xy$. (a) Find all equilibria for this system and determine their stability. (b) Find the Hamiltonian of the system. (c) Find a solution curve that connects a saddle point. (d) Does the curve obtained in (c) connect any other saddle points?

Below is my answer to parts $(a)$ and $(b)$:

a)

There are four equilibrium points here, all of which can be found using relatively simple algebra. They are $E_1 = (0,0), E_2 = (0,1), E_{3,4} = \left( \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, - \frac{1}{2} \right)$. The stability of these is found below:

$$Df\left( x, y \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 2x & 1-2y \\ -1-2y & -2x\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$Df\left( E_1 \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{matrix}\right) \implies \lambda_{1,2} = \pm i$$

Thus $E_1$ is a center.

$$Df\left( E_2 \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ -3 & 0\end{matrix}\right) \implies \lambda_{1,2} = \pm \sqrt 3$$
Thus $E_2$ is a saddle.

$$Df\left( E_3 \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} \sqrt 3 & 2 \\ 0 & - \sqrt 3\end{matrix}\right) \implies \lambda_{1,2} = \pm \sqrt 3$$
Thus $E_3$ is a saddle.

$$Df\left( E_4 \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} -\sqrt{3} & 2 \\ 0 & \sqrt 3\end{matrix}\right) \implies \lambda_{1,2} = \pm \sqrt 3$$
Thus $E_4$ is a saddle.

b)

$$H(x,y) = \int (y + x^2 - y^2)dy = \frac{1}{2}y^2 + x^2 y - \frac{1}{3}y^3 + f(x)$$
Thus
$$-\frac{d}{dx} H(x,y) = -\frac{d}{dx} [x^2 y + f(x)] = \dot y = -x-2xy$$
which implies
$$-2xy -f'(x) = -x-2xy \implies f'(x) = x$$
thus $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$. So the Hamiltonian is
$$H(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}y^2 + x^2 y - \frac{1}{3}y^3 + \frac{1}{2}x^2$$.

Now that I have all of this information however, (c) seems like a strangely vague question. Is all I have to do here plug in a saddle point and see what solution it gives me? A walkthrough of this would be helpful, and then would in turn help me with part (d). Thanks in advance for any and all advice!

Comment: For a Hamiltonian system, solutions are level curves of the Hamiltonian (sort of like "conservation of energy"). Note that $H$ gives the same value at $E_2$, $E_3$, and $E_4$; hence there exist solution curves between each pair. The wording on part (c) is rather strange to...."connects a saddle point" to what?

Comment: There lies part of my problem. I'm not quite sure how to handle it, and this was all I was given.

Comment: It should help to notice that $y+\frac12$ is a factor of $H(x,y)-\frac16$: $$H(x,y)-\frac16=-\frac13\left(y+\frac12\right) (1 - 3 x^2 - 2 y + y^2).$$ From there it is straightforward to draw the phase portrait and so to interpret what c) could be: seems likely that it means "Find a solution curve that *is asymptotic* to a saddle point".